# How to send/upload multiple files to rails API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular5, multipartform-data

I have to upload multiple files to API developed in rails. It requires data to be sent as following.

`document[][file]`

I have tried to create this type of form data object but I am failing. Uploading files through application is giving me following error.

```
    name: "HttpErrorResponse"
    ok: false
    status: 422
    statusText: "Unprocessable Entity"
```

But if I am trying with postman, I am getting success response.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS6FL.jpg)

Please guide me for this problem.

Comment: can check log for it so you might found what's issue while request coming from application and postman

Comment: I am a front-end developer and working on angular side. whereas there's another person who is working on rails application. He develops and deploys API and gives me its url and postman dump. So the situation is I can not dig into the code of rails and I am not having knowledge of rails.

Comment: ok, check curl command in postman or send similar parameters from application like postman because we can't investigate it on stackoverflow community

Comment: Doing that gives me "We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)" error.